# Why don't more orthodox Jews homeschool?

Tags: yeshiva-school, social-convention

Given the significant cost of Jewish day-school tuition (at least in the US) and the negative experience that some students have in those day schools (I'm speaking from my own experience as well as those of friends, my children, and their friends). I would like to know why more orthodox Jews do not home-school? Are there halachic reasons? Has any research been done to see if there are social taboos that are in play? Other reasons?

[this question is related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22396/how-does-judaism-regard-homeschooling)

Comment: off the cuff, I would need to find capable teachers for twice as many subjects. That is daunting.

Comment: In New York State homeschooling requires a yearly application to the NYS Dept. Of Education. Students must also take state reading and math tests. To monitor their progress. In general, parents usually do the teaching.

Comment: Actually, homeschooling is the ideal. Centralized education only arose because of those who couldn't be taught by their fathers.

Comment: A major problem with this would be the absence of social life for homeschooled children.

Comment: @LiquidMetal As a homeschooled kid, it's not. There are youth groups (e.g. Bnei Akiva), shul, community things, and of course, homeschool gatherings.

Comment: Primarily Opinion Based?

Comment: @DoubleAA "are there halachic reasons?" and "has any research been done?" doesn't sound opinion-based.  However, answers that don't address that, instead offering personal opinions, don't answer the question and should be removed.

Comment: It's expensive, social life of child

Comment: http://www.jewishpress.com/sections/family/parenting-our-children/homeschooling-on-the-rise-in-orthodox-community/2013/07/19/

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38278/4794

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is very hard for a Jewish family to home-school their sons in particular because the mothers do not normally have the background to teach them Torah, and the fathers normally work / are in kollel and are therefore unable to spend their time teaching them.